# Python setup.py without root

Tags: python, matlab, setup.py

I would like to install some Python module, namely the [MATLAB Engine](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html). MATLAB is installed globally under `/usr/local/sw/matlab`, so I change to the  corresponding directory and then run `setup.py` as explained in the linked documentation. However, I am not root, so I added the `--user` flag, as documented by the official [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme).

So this is what I get:

`> python setup.py install --user
 running install
 running build
 running build_py
 creating build
 error: could not create 'build': Permission denied`

Apparently it tries to build the module in the current directory, where I have no write access. I can sidestep this by running

`python setup.py build --build-base=/path/to/temp/build/dir`

But then I don't know how to install that. Also I cannot combine those 2 approaches as `install` does not recognize the `--build-base` option.

I furthermore tried to copy the whole `matlabroot/extern/engines/python` directory somewhere else and run `python setup.py install --user` there, but this yields

`error: The installation of MATLAB is corrupted.  Please reinstall MATLAB or contact Technical Support for assistance.`

I guess it does not find the `matlabroot` anymore.

So how do I build and install some source located somewhere under `/usr...` without being root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) or [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to deal with this kind of issues.

Edit: As we went a bit deeper into issue itself, we managed to figure out the answer.

If you wish to use virtual environment: `python setup.py build --build-base="/path/to/directory_you_can_write_to" install --prefix="/path/to/virtualenv/" --user`

If you wish to accomplish what @Feodoran asked for: `python setup.py build --build-base="/path/to/directory_you_can_write_to" install --user`

Useful links:

- https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-matlab-engine-api-for-python-in-nondefault-locations.html
- https://python.org/3.2/install

Comment: How would having a different location for the python binary help with the location issue of the build directory?

Comment: You can setup different env for your MATLAB needs and avoid permission issues.

Comment: Then please elaborate how. Because if I just run `~/tmp/matlab/bin/python3 setup.py install --user`, where `~/tmp/matlab` is my venv directory, I get the same problems as before.

Comment: With `--prefix`. This is from their docs `cd "matlabroot\extern\engines\python";
python setup.py install --prefix="installdir` where `installdir` is virtualenv localtion. Here's documentation: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-matlab-engine-api-for-python-in-nondefault-locations.html

Comment: I got it now. venv is not needed! But `python setup.py build --build-base="builddir" install --user` does the trick.

Comment: This worked for me, without privileged user. `python setup.py build --build-base="/path/to/directory_i_can_write_to" install --prefix="/path/to/virtualenv/"` Not sure why `install` doesn't work in your case. Maybe try `--home` instead of --build-base or check other alternatives here: https://docs.python.org/3.2/install/ Edit: Glad you managed to work it out, your comment didn't update for me.

Comment: I just wrote that `install` does work for me, as long as I correctly combine it with `--build-base` and `--user`.

Comment: Check my edit, I didn't saw your previous comment when I posted mine.

Comment: If you replace your answer by that one comment, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: Let me know if you wish to add anything else that was helpful as well.